# React: Confusion about how useEffect hook works

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So here's the code I'm confused about:

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
    const [starWarsData, setStarWarsData] = React.useState({})
 
    console.log(starWarsData)
    React.useEffect(function() {
        fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setStarWarsData(data))
    }, [starWarsData])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <pre>{JSON.stringify(starWarsData, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This code will constantly be re-rendering the component in an infinite loop, but I dont understand why that is. In the `useEffect` function, it uses a fetch request for some data about Star Wars and will execute `setStarWarsData` on that data.

My understanding of this code is that when it **first** renders the component, it will then call the `useEffect` function (as always). The `useEffect` function will then change the state of the variable `starWarsData` which will then re-render the whole component however according to my flawed logic, the `useEffect` function shouldnt be executed after this current render of the component as the variable `starWarsData` is the same between the previous render and this render. If you put a `console.log(starWarsData)`, the `starWarsData` variable will have the same value between the previous render of the component and the current render of the component, that is both will be objects that have the same content inside the objects.

Why is this logic wrong? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Two objects with the same content aren't equal (eg: `{foo: "bar"} === {foo: "bar"}` gives `false`). React uses `Object.is()` to compare the new state with the previous one (which is similar to `===`), so it thinks the objects have changed and will attempt to rerender (as both `Object.is` and `===` are checking if the objects _references_ are the same, not their content).

Comment: @NickParsons so when the `starWarsData` variable is set inside the `useEffect` function, it replaces it with a new object that has a different memory address to the old one, thereby to React, the values have changed because the memory references arent the same, hence infinite loop?

Comment: Yep, that's spot on.

Comment: You are not using `starWarsData` inside your effect. Consequently, it shouldn't be listed as dependency.

Comment: @knittl yeah it was just a thought experiment, so that I can clear my confusion about these concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` has two parameters, the first parameter is the function you want it to call.

The second parameter is an array to watch and call your function whenever it change (in addition to when the component is mounted first).

Your passing the state `starWarsData` in the array and inside of your function setting this state, the state change triggers `useEffect` to call your function again, creating an infinite loop!

Pass an empty array if you want the function to get called only on component mount.

```
React.useEffect(function() {
    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setStarWarsData(data))
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, you can also compare if the object is matching or not before updating the state so it doesn't necessarily re-render.

You can check the object change by `JSON.stringify`.

To note here, there could be times when the structure of the data might not be in the same order in JSON and you might need to tweak it, but that's least of our concern here.

Your hook will look something like this:

```
React.useEffect(function() {
    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(JSON.stringify(data) === JSON.stringify(starWarsData) 
                {
                  setStarWarsData(data))
                }
            }
         },
[starWarsData])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is your dependency on the `useEffect` hook.

`useEffect` hook will be executed once on the component mount, and your dependency will be changed each time.

You are updating `starWarsData` inside `useEffect` and using that data as a dependency so on the execution of `useEffect`,  `starWarsData` will be updated and on the update of `starWarsData`, `useEffect` will be executed creating an endless loop.

So add an empty array as a dependency to execute the use effect only once.